# How to use IAppBuilder-based Owin Middleware in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, owin

ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET vNext) is OWIN based like Katana was, but has different abstractions.  Notably `IAppBuilder` has been replaced by `IApplicationBuilder`.  Many middleware libraries depend on `IAppBuilder` and have not been updated to support ASP.NET 5

How can I use this OWIN middleware in ASP.NET 5 middleware.  Both are OWIN based so it should be possible.

`Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.OwinExtensions` does provide a `UseOwin` method, but it is based on the low-level OWIN signatures so cannot be used with methods expecting `IAppBuilder`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: you can now use the [`AspNet.Hosting.Katana.Extensions` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Hosting.Katana.Extensions/) for that.

---

Here's a slightly different version, that uses `AppBuilder.DefaultApp`:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseOwinAppBuilder(this IApplicationBuilder app, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }

    if (configuration == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    return app.UseOwin(setup => setup(next =>
    {
        var builder = new AppBuilder();
        var lifetime = (IApplicationLifetime) app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IApplicationLifetime));

        var properties = new AppProperties(builder.Properties);
        properties.AppName = app.ApplicationServices.GetApplicationUniqueIdentifier();
        properties.OnAppDisposing = lifetime.ApplicationStopping;
        properties.DefaultApp = next;

        configuration(builder);

        return builder.Build<Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>>();
    }));
}
```

Note that referencing `Microsoft.Owin` makes your app incompatible with `dnxcore50` (Core CLR).

Comment: I do not understand the full implications but this works and it seems like it may be more robust because of the extra property assignments.  Just to make sure I am not missing something, this implementation also requires referencing `Microsoft.Owin` making the implementations the same in that respect?

Comment: Absolutely, it depends on AppBuilder, which is part of Microsoft.Owin. Trying to refactor it to avoid referencing Microsoft.Owin would be a nice exercise, but I'm not sure it would be worth it, as you would still have to port the OWIN/Katana middleware you'd like to use to Core CLR.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer link fixed.

Comment: @Pinpoint I am in dire need of this method. How i can use this method in my startup.cs(dotnetcore2.0).   How i use it in app.UseOwin(pipeline =>
    {
        pipeline(next => OwinHello);
    }); Please suggest

Comment: AspNet.Hosting.Katana.Extensions package is deprecated now, is there any other open source nuget package with this method? Don't want to copy it from project to project =(

Answer (score 3):

The oft cited reference that the frameworks are compatible is [an extension method build by Thinktecture for supporting their IdentityServer3 on ASP.NET 5](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/vNext/source/HostvNext/Config/IApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs).

That method is specific to IdentityServer and does not support the request being processed by any middleware registered later in the AspNet pipeline (it does not call the next component).

This adapts the method to address those shortcomings:

```
internal static class IApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
  public static void UseOwin(
    this IApplicationBuilder app,
    Action<IAppBuilder> owinConfiguration )
  {
    app.UseOwin(
      addToPipeline =>
        {
          addToPipeline(
            next =>
              {
                var builder = new AppBuilder();

                owinConfiguration( builder );

                builder.Run( ctx => next( ctx.Environment ) );

                Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> appFunc =
                  (Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>)
                  builder.Build( typeof( Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> ) );

                return appFunc;
              } );
        } );
  }
}
```

It can be used as follows:

```
app.UseOwin(
    owin =>
        {
            // Arbitrary IAppBuilder registrations can be placed in this block

            // For example, this extension can be provided by
            // NWebsec.Owin or Thinktecture.IdentityServer3
            owin.UseHsts();
        } );

// ASP.NET 5 components, like MVC 6, will still process the request
// (assuming the request was not handled by earlier middleware)
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: While trying to replicate the IApplicationBuilderExtension found in the link provided, I get this error: Method name expected. The line being referred to is the line containing the second mention of the addToPipeline

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply @vossad01. I indeed have reference Owin (     `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin` can't be resolved but      `Microsoft.Owin` can be) and gives the type of     `addToPipeline` as     `IAppBuilder`.

Comment: @MRainzo, It sounds like you are missing the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin`.  If adding this does not fix the issue, I will probably need to know what version of ASP.NET 5 you are using.

What you describes suggests you are missing the mentioned library and have the code above (rather than the linked code). Thus, it is seeing `UseOwin` as a call to the above method (which would have a lambda parameter of type `IAppBuilder`).

Comment: when I tried the linked method,@vossad01, it gave an error on the app.UseOwin. Then I tried to replicate the code above and got the error I reported to you. Still can't get `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin` resolved. Using `@System.Environment.Version.ToString()` I got the version number as 4.0.30319.0

Comment: @MRainzo, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80220/discussion-between-vossad01-and-mrainzo).