# What version of SignalR am I supposed to be running?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core

I'm bamboozled by the aspnetcore and aspnet versioning. I cannot for the life of me determine what version of SignalR I need for my current project. Here's a snippet from my project.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    },
"frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
},
```

I've tried "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.2.0-*" just like the example in [this sample project](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/dev/samples/SignalRSample.Web/project.json)

I've tried installing "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR": "2.2.1" from Nuget.

I've tried changing my target framework from 4.6 to core to 4.5.1.

In each attempt I've received a different compilation error...

Comment: I'm using `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server": "0.1.0-rtm-21431"` with aspnet Core and it works fine. I suppose `0.2.0-*` should work too. You should not use anything within `Microsoft.AspNet.` namespace - that's RC1 of aspnet Core and is not compatible with version 1.0.0.

Comment: We are currently using SignalR 2.2.0 (`"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR": "2.2.0"` in package.json) with Owin on framework 4.5.2 (till new version is released).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890084/using-signalr-2-in-asp-net-5-application) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742028/how-to-use-iappbuilder-based-owin-middleware-in-asp-net-5) for more info on how to enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are very brave and want to use the next version of ASP.NET Core (1.1 development builds) your only choice is to run `0.1.0-rtm-21431` as you can see in the project's project.json file on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/blob/3.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/project.json).

Please note that the sample is from `3.0.0` tag and not from the `master` tag which references the new ASP.NET Core 1.1 nightly builds (only available on myget, not nuget.org).

This is valid for any samples related to ASP.NET Core: Always use a specific tag from the sources, never use examples from master unless you want to test with the nightly builds!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all! I couldn't have done it without everyone's input.

I had been referencing both the default [nuget feed](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) and by Tseng's answer this [myget feed](https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json)

I only reference the aspnetcirelease feed and it compiles now using the "0.1.0-rtm-21634" version

[This question+comment were also useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093446/697827)